# datetime related issue from sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to have the output of my MySQL query like this.
In date time I want to get the previous year data as only year and present year data as month and year.

Example

```
2011
2012
2013
Jan2014
Feb2014
Mar2014
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Add required data samples and your approach as well

Comment: Please give some more description so that people can understand the question.

Comment: Please be clear in your question. And give the code that you already have. Also google before your Ask Question.

Comment: i have a date time column that should give me the output as  i have mentioned above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the below :

```
select id,case 
when  extract(year from dt)='2014'
then to_char(dt,'MON-YYYY')
when extract(year from dt) < '2014'
then to_char(dt,'YYYY')
end
from table1
```

output:

```
1   2013
2   JAN-2014
```

Comment: hey it is for oracle but i made it for my sql and its workin fine thanks a lot ........

Comment: hey its working fine..excellent,. but small issue that can i make distinct of previous years data which is replicating as 2013,2013....with present year...

Comment: Do u mean to say that you want if there are 5 records in 2013, you want only one row with 2013?